# Is a POST action to a secure domain always secure

Tags: php, html, security

Is a form on a regular domain (**http**://www.domainname.com/form.php) with the following action tag:

```
<form action="https://www.domainname.com/mail.php" method="POST">
```

indeed secure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The form can be intercepted on its way to the user (a man in the middle attack) and the page modified so that the data will be submitted somewhere else (possibly with JavaScript so the data theft is harder to spot).

The request to the HTTPS site will be secure, but not in time to avoid the data being intercepted.

Also, the page containing the form will not be marked as secure, which will not illicit trust from the user.

Answer (score -1):

Technically yes. But if the HTML for the form is on an unsecured page, you can't trust the form itself.

Comment: Why the downvote? If the unsecured page is intercepted, the form could not be pointing to the secure page anymore. Please explain.